# MongoDB unwind commands

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm trying to unwind an array inside a document.

```
{ //document
    ...
    parameters : [{...}, {...}, ...]
}
```

Here is a working command:

```
db.getCollection('inventory').aggregate([
    { $unwind : "$parameters" }
]);
```

I'm trying to use `db.runCommand` to do the same task:

```
db.runCommand({
    aggregate: "inventory",
    pipeline: [{ $unwind: "$parameters" }]
});
```

But with this second options, I'm getting this error:

> aggregation result exceeds maximum document size (16MB)

**Aren't these commands the same? Why the second one is not working?**

I'm using Mongo PHP Driver for PHP 7, that's why I'm aggregating in this way.

Comment: Setting [allowDiskUse](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) to true will probably solve the problem. Nevertheless, why that only happens with runCommand is a good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`db.runCommand` returns the result inside one document. So, all the aggregation result is larger than 16MB. Setting `batchSize` at `cursor` option might solve the problem.

Using [MongoDB::execute](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.execute.php), I can execute a query in this way: `db.collection.aggregate(...` just passing the original mongo syntax.